# undefined method `model_name' in a partial rendered by different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, simple-form, controllers

I'm trying to render this form:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <%= simple_form_for @prospect, 
    :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'prospects'),
    :method => 'post' do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :name,  placeholder: 'Name', label: false %>
    <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'Email', label: false %>
    <%= f.input :interests, placeholder: 'Tell us what you were searching for', label: false, value: params[:search]  %>    
    <%= f.error :base %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", :class=> "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Using this partial:

```
 <%= render partial: 'prospects/novideo_capture' %>
```

The partial is in a view controlled by Videos#index controller, and I keep getting this error: 'undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class'

This is my prospects controller:

```
class ProspectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @prospects = Prospect.all
  end

  def new
    @prospect = Prospect.new
  end

  def create
    @prospect = Prospect.new(params[:prospect])
    if @prospect.save
    render "thanks_for_interest"
    else
    render "novideo_capture"
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what I'm going wrong, although I'm pretty sure it's a simple solution.  I've seen a lot of similar questions around SO and tried all their answers, but none of them seem to work for this situation.

Thanks for any help...

EDIT: Adding

```
@prospect = Prospect.new
```

to the videos index controller stops the error occurring, but I don't feel it's the right way to do this.  It also doesn't actually make the form use the prospects controller.

EDIT2: I now have the partial rendering correctly (I think), and my videos#index calls the partial like this:

```
 <%= render partial: 'prospects/novideo_capture', :prospect => @prospect %>
```

Then simple_form in the partial looks like this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <%= simple_form_for :prospect, 
    :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'prospects'),
    :method => 'post' do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

However it's not actually submitting the form with the prospects controller.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Anything showing up in the console when you submit the form?

Comment: Yes, but it's being processed by the video#index controller for some reason, although it's picking up the params info I'm feeding it:Processing by VideosController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PvgOtUlXxzTp6hNZNSNtO8AyPXx0GP1dNfLi4ZJ+72I=", "prospect"=>{"name"=>"Test", "email"=>"test@test.com", "interests"=>"Testing"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your markup. You're wrapping a simple_form inside another form. Since the first form tag has no action associated with it (`<form class="form-inline">`), that form will submit against the current URL, which is the video#index.

You're going to want something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for :prospect, :url => etc, :method => 'post', :class => "form-inline" do |f|
  ...
<% end %>
```

Losing the leading (redundant) form-inline form tag and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something obvious like that!